# Using IE11 Debug Tools or IE11 in Windows 8

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, ie-developer-tools, internet-explorer-11

Anybody knows if it is possible to run the IE11 debug tools (F12) on a Windows 8.0 machine? I think there is no download of IE11 for windows 8.0 yet? (I can't install Windows 8.1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not currently possible to run IE11, and thus the F12 developer tools bundled with it, on Windows 8.

IE has only been announced for Windows 8.1 and Windows 7. The preview is currently only available bundled with Windows 8.1 (Edit: and now for Windows 7). As windows 8.1 will be a free upgrade, it may be than IE11 will never come out for Windows 8, but that is just speculation.